# Can ping websites but not view them in a browser

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, internet-connection

So I'm having internet browsing issues hoping this makes sense to someone.

I reboot my PC windows 10 and it works fine, but leave it on overnight and come back to it, the internet seems to drops out, but....

I had a few chrome tabs open overnight. This morning some of them still connected while others did not. I could hit refresh and it would display, others went to a this site can't be reached error.

Opening a new tab and going to a new site didn't work.
Opening a new tab and going to a site that still worked in the other tab worked in the new tab.
Searching Google in a new tab worked. In fact any Google service worked.
Facebook didn't
Twitter didn't
Random websites, nope.

Just Google stuff plus a few lucky existing tabs

Oh, and I can use ping in the command prompt to ping any website I like and it'll respond with 0% loss

Other browsers do not work either

Dafaq is going on?

Comment: did you try clearing cache and cookies?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that it might be losing DNS.  Do the following:

Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator

Then: netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt

Then: ipconfig /flushdns

Then: restart the computer

Now test to ensure Internet is working properly.

Then after fully testing the above, also update the firmware on the router as that may also be part of the issue.

Comment: That seemed to work even without resetting the computer. Weird thing is that I've tried your suggestion before, but it hasn't

Comment: I added a note about also updating the router firmware.

Comment: It's not the router. Tried 2 different routers both same issue. Other PC's connected to the same router do not have issues

Comment: Try running DISM and SFC.  Use an admin command prompt again.  dism.exe /online  /cleanup-image  /restorehealth followed by sfc /scannow and then again restart. If not the router, then it appears to be a Windows issue.